# How to install after downloading the files?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

I have downloaded numpy-1.4.0rc2.zip from sourceforge and have expanded the contents to a folder:

```
Directory: D:\temp\numpy-1.4.0rc2


Mode                LastWriteTime     Length Name
----                -------------     ------ ----
d----         9/10/2015     13:47            doc
d----         9/10/2015     13:48            numpy
-a---         9/10/2015     13:47       1620 COMPATIBILITY
-a---         9/10/2015     13:47        687 DEV_README.txt
-a---         9/10/2015     13:47       4732 INSTALL.txt
-a---         9/10/2015     13:47       1543 LICENSE.txt
-a---         9/10/2015     13:47        785 MANIFEST.in
-a---         9/10/2015     13:47       1613 PKG-INFO
-a---         9/10/2015     13:47        783 README.txt
-a---         9/10/2015     13:47       5989 setup.py
-a---         9/10/2015     13:47        149 setupegg.py
-a---         9/10/2015     13:47       4161 setupscons.py
-a---         9/10/2015     13:47        154 setupsconsegg.py
-a---         9/10/2015     13:47       5010 site.cfg.example
-a---         9/10/2015     13:47       3109 THANKS.txt
```

INSTALL.txt and README.txt do not offer any installation instructions.  What should the next step be?  I tried `python setup.py` but got:

```
ImportError: No module named '__builtin__'
```

I am using Python 3.4 on Windows 10.

Comment: Is this programming related? :/

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish here? `numpy-1.4.0rc2.zip` is an ancient release candidate. Can you elaborate why you want to use this one instead of following the installation guide in the docs?

Comment: Sorry, I was following the instructions from http://www.scipy.org/install.html and didn't realize that 1.4 is not the latest.  Will search again.

Comment: If you are completely new to python and the scipy stack, you may want to use the instructions on how to install with `anaconda` on that page.